# Merging save files

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

My primary save file is currently on my Wii U. Out of things to do when out of the house, I decided to make another save file on my 3DS. After playing for a bit, I wondered if it was possible to merge the two separate save files into one, using the transfer data program. Is this possible or would one save file overwrite the other during the transfer process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't merge save files, one file would be overwritten